# How do I use the value in the link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am not sure how to ask this question and I have tried to look for the solution but no luck since I don't know what to search for... So I had a linkbutton to direct the user to the addtocart.aspx with the id of the product and the link should look like this

```
addtocart.aspx/?id=1
```

My problem is how do I use the id value that is in the link I redirect the user to and save it to another database for cart. This is what I current progress and still cant get the id to show up (This code is under Page Load of addtocart.aspx)

```cs
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    String contact_id = Id;
    int intTest = Convert.ToInt32(contact_id);

    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Id=" + intTest))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        string id = row["Id"].ToString();
                        string Product_Name = row["Product_Name"].ToString();
                        string Product_Price = row["Product_Price"].ToString();
                        string username = Session["Username"].ToString();

                        con.Close();
                        con.Open();
                        string query = "INSERT INTO Cart (Guest_Id, Product_Name, Product_Price) values (@Guest_Id, @Product_Name, @Product_Price)";

                        SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(query, con);

                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Name", Product_Name);
                        cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Product_Price", Product_Price);

                        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        Response.Redirect("Dining.aspx");

                        con.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @GSerg, i checked the solution there and not sure but it doesnt seem to fix my problem. my problem is i don't know how to use the parameter in the url for the code...

Comment: It shows how to do exactly that.

Comment: @GSerg I guess i dont know what to look at...haha im pretty noob at this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get query string parameters just use [`Request.QueryString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.8). So,

```
// this gets the 'id' parameter from rthe query string, as a string
string contact_id = Request.QueryString["id"];
```